# Regex: How to (better) optimize text from/for messages

Tags: javascript, php, regex

*Since this question does not contain a specific question on regex but more on it's design/approach, it might take a while to understand the requirements and their dependencies. I have done everything I can to make it as easy as possible with this <s>[fully working yet not elegant solution](https://api.sefzig.net/dialog/test/regex/)</s>(deadlink).*

---

I need to optimize text in a messaging platform that is being created/edited by others and may have to be sanitized with regex. All optimizations need to be done with one single regex, since these happen often and are quite expensive (or am I wrong on this?). Furthermore the regex needs to be language-agnostic (at least compatible with Javascript and Php). Last but not least, the optimized text must not contain (additional) Html as it is used in a text-only environment.

### Requirements

Optimize lines

- Remove single lines
- Do not remove single lines that end with two|no spaces (thus allow editors to force a newline)
- Do not remove empty lines (double line breaks)
- Do not remove single lines that start with symbol|char|digit|entity+space (raw lists)
- Condense multiple consecutive empty lines (double line breaks) to one double line break

Optimize spaces

- Remove excess spaces
- Do not remove spaces at the end of a sentence

Optimize comments

- Remove single line comments
- Do not remove trailing comments

Overall

- Preserve Html and do not add Html

### Intermediate solution

So far, my solution is to combine 4 regexes which 'match' my requirements and **get replaced by a single space**:

- Matches single lines while leaving empty lines intact and preserving raw lists:  `\n(?!\n|[-_.○•♥→›>+%\/*~=] |[a-zA-Z_1-9+][\.|\)|\:|\*])` (the length is due to several list-style-types I want to support)
- Matches excess empty lines: `(\n+)(?=\n\n)`
- Matches excess spaces: `+`
- Matches single line comments (while ignoring trailing comments):  `^\n?\/\/ .+\n`

To make the optimization rather inexpensive, I concatenate them with `|` to one single regex which I can use in Javascript (as well as Php).

```js
r = new RegExp(" \n(?!\n|[-_.○•♥→›>+%\/*~=] |[a-zA-Z_1-9+][.):*] )|(\n+)(?=\n\n)| + |^\n?\/\/ .+\n", "gm");
i = document.getElementById("input").innerHTML;
p = " ";
o = i.replace(r, p);
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = o;
```

```css
#input, #output { width: 100%; height: 88vh; }
#input { display: none; } #output { border: none; }
```

```html
<textarea id="input">

MAKE PARAGRAPHS

This is the first paragraph. 
Some sentences end with newlines. 
Some don't. We need to cope with that.

This is the second paragraph. 
It contains some  unnecessary   spaces. 
Even at the end of a line.    

This is the third paragraph. 
Some sentences end with question- and exclamation-marks. 
I hope that is ok for you. Is it? That's great! Really. 


KEEP LISTS

This is an unordered list, starting with a minus+space: 

- This is the first item. 
- This is the second item. 
- This is the third item. 

Here is an unordered list, starting with entity|symbol+space: 

• This is the second item.
> This is the third item. // Works in php only 
* This is the fifth item. 

This is a (manually) ordered lists, starting with char|digit+entity+space: 

1. This is the first item. 
b) This is the second item. 
3: This is the third item. 

Here is a mathematical list, starting with operators: 

+ Plus 
- Minus 
% Percentage 
/ Division 
* Multiply 
~ Like 
= Equal 

These are (manually) ordered lists, which are not summed up because they do not end with a space: 

1 This is the first item.
b This is the second item.
I like the third item.

First: This works.
Second: It works great.
Third: That is nice!


KEEP HTML

The input text may contain <a href="https://example.com" target="_blank">Html</a>. 
The output text must simply keep it for further processing. 
The output must not add Html as it is processed in a text-only environment. 
I know this sounds stupid, but it isn't. 


REMOVE COMMENTS

Single/whole line comments are being removed.

// Sources 
// Removing single lines: https://regex101.com/r/qU1eP8/5 
// Removing comments: https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=996552 

// Tests 
// Dialog: https://api.sefzig.net/dialog/test/regex/ 
// Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/goromad/edit?output 
// Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Xz5atA/2 
// Regexr: https://regexr.com/45svm 

Thank you, regex ♥ // Problem solved



~Fin~
</textarea>
<textarea id="output"><!-- Press "Run" --></textarea>
```

### My request

Since I am not a regex-expert and my approach feels cumbersome, I'd like to hear your suggestions. I know Regex is expensive and everything can be done better.

You might wonder about a few details I haven't mentioned here for the sake of clarity. You also might want to test my Regexes. This is why I have set up a sandbox, isolating the requirements (Regexes), containing an example text with all use-cases as well as a detailed description:

- <s>https://api.sefzig.net/dialog/test/regex/</s>(deadlink)

In case you want to use the features of great tools out there, here you go:

- Regexr: https://regexr.com/45svm
- Regex101: https://regex101.com/r/Xz5atA/2
- Jsbin: https://jsbin.com/goromad/edit?output

### Thank you

for helping me straighten this important feature of my [messaging platform](https://dialog.sefzig.net)! Please feel free to enhance my approach, suggest an alternative or use the results in your own project ♥

*This is my first question on stack overflow. I have researched a lot. Please bear with me if I have done anything wrong and help me fix that.*

Comment: Do you have a specific regex question ?

Comment: @sln Yes, I'd like to find a better approach for the described requirements (if that deserves to be called 'specific'..).

Comment: If you can't be selectively specific, then you want someone to spend a lot of time analyzing your entire design, approach and methods in general. You might want to consider hiring a contractor.

Comment: Since you have a working solution, this also looks somewhat off-topic for StackOverflow. You may consider asking at [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @sln I updated the intro to reflect your comprehensible remark.

Comment: @trincot Thank you for the advice! I'll look that up.

Comment: You're welcome. It's been deleted.